# How to extract an entry to nsdictionary base on a condition and copy it another array or nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to check if the element inside the nsdictionary is not equal to normal, then copy that element to an array to be served as my datasource of my UITable.

Here is an example of entry:

```
Trailer =     {
        BodyDoorsCondition = Normal;
        Breaks = Dent;
        HandSideRails = Normal;
        KingPinUpperPlate = Normal;
        LandingGear = Scratches;
        Lights = Normal;
        MudFlaps = Normal;
        RearEndProtection = Normal;
        Reflectors = Normal;
        SideSteps = Normal;
        StripCurtains = Normal;
        Suspension = Normal;
        TieDowns = Normal;
    };
```

I need to move the LandingGear to a new array that i can use as the value of my UITable.

thanks for any tips or assitance.

Comment: LandingGear and Breaks to be exact.

Comment: Yes, you can use keysOfEntriesPassingTest    
ref http://samplecodebank.blogspot.in/2013/05/nsdictionary-keysofentriespassingtest.html

Comment: Edit your question and add that code;   it is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @Jageen do you have exact example of it i can't follow the given example, apology and thank you for your reply. the code i posted works but i also need to get the value of the element that matched the condition. probably instead of array i will be needing a NSMutableDictionary again.

Comment: I tried putting '' on my comment but it didn't work. how can I mark that as a code.@bbum

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary *dataDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                NSMutableArray *dataSource=[NSMutableArray array];
                NSArray *allKeys=[tractorDict allKeys];
                for (id key in allKeys) {
                    if ([[tractorDict objectForKey:key]isEqualToString:@"Normal"]==NO) {
                        [dataSource addObject:key];
                        [dataDict setValue:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>]
                        
                    }
                }`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use keysOfEntriesPassingTest

```
NSSet * selectedKeys = [Trailer keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
                        {
                            return ![obj isEqualToString:@"Normal"];
                        }];
```

Comment: i am getting the opposite and I cannot put ! for not equal. I need to capture all that is not normal and add this to a NSDictionary together with the value if its Dent or Scratches. thank you again for you attention

Comment: @baste I don't understand, why can't you put ! for not equal?

Comment: where will i put the ! for equal? sorry Im newbie with objective c

Comment: `return ![obj isEqualToString:@"Normal"];`

Comment: you can also compare it with NO. `return [obj isEqualToString:@"Normal"] == NO;`

Comment: thank you got it now, but how can you copy the value of the element, im just getting the key for it

Comment: `NSArray *selectedObjects = [obj objectsForKeys: selectedKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];`

Answer (score 0):

this code works and i just want to share

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            NSMutableArray *dataSource=[NSMutableArray array];
            NSArray *allKeys=[tractorDict allKeys];

            for (id key in allKeys) {
                if ([[tractorDict objectForKey:key]isEqualToString:@"Normal"]==NO) {
                    [dataSource addObject:key];

                    [dataDict setValue:[tractorDict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *Trailer;
[Trailer enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if (![obj isEqualToString:@"Normal"]) {
        [array addObject:key];
    }
}];
```